# how to decompile .jasper files into .jrxml files

Tags: jasper-reports, decompiling

I lost all my *.jrxml* files, but I have *.jasper* files. Can I decompile *.jasper* files to *.jrxml* files? If yes, that would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*.jasper files can be opened directly from ireport, Ireport decompile automatically the file.

Comment: I should google first before wasting my time designing report. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlWriter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;

class JasperToXml {

    public static String sourcePath;
    public static String destinationPath;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sourcePath = "..File1.jasper";
        destinationPath = "...File2.jrxml";

        JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(sourcePath);
        JRXmlWriter.writeReport(report, destinationPath, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, it helps me indeed. But the jrxml file who was decompiled from a jasper file,can not show correctly. Fortunately, I get all the sql from the jrxml file.